# match columns values qlikview

Tags: expression, qlikview

In one table there is column product

```
Product 
1233-901
3945-847
3956-234
3462
2940
2357
```

and in table 2 i have product column and data is

```
product
1233
3495
3456
3462
2940
2357
```

i want to match values of these column and get only first 4 characters .. so i tried this

first i load this in tab1

```
    LOAD 
     left(Product,5) as Product_code,    
FROM
F2.xlsx
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is PM1);
```

and in second tab i load this

```
Load Product FROM
F3q.xlsx
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is PM2);
```

but i did not get data ... i get data like this

```
   Product_code   Product 
    1233             - 
    3945             -
    3956             -
    3462          3462
    2940          2940
    2357          2357
      -            1233
      -            3495
      -            3456
```

where as i am trying to get data like this

```
Product_code   Product 
1233             1233
3945             3495
3956             3496
3462             3462
2940            2940
2357            2357
```

Comment: you should use `left(Product,4)` or if you want to stick with 5 then trim the result to remove any extra spaces: `trim( left(Product, 5)  )`

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
trim(left(Product, 5))
```

and probably use

```
INNER JOIN(Table1)
LOAD ...
```

you can share your dataset so I will take a look